# cant reach docker container from outside host with port mapping

Tags: docker, networking

I am using a really simple docker-compose file from here:

https://github.com/brandonserna/flask-docker-compose

this is the docker compose file:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  flask-app-service:
    build: ./app
    volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/src/app
      - .:/user/src
    ports:
      - 5555:9999
```

However I can only reach the app from outside network when I am using port 80.

```
    ports:
      - 80:9999
```

When I am using for example port 8000. I cant reach the container from outside network.
From the local machine I can reach the app. (Tested with wget localhost:8000)

```
    ports:
      - 8000:9999
```

iptables -L gives me this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:9999
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:http

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: From where are you trying to reach the `flask-app-service` container? Port bindings only apply to the host system. If external Docker containers need to interact with it you will have to provide an `overlay` network or create a `bridge` network and connect them manually. [Documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/#extended-description).

Comment: I want to reach it from my home. And the PC with the flask-app is at an another city.

Comment: Then connecting to it when the `flask-app-service` port is bound to the host's port 80 works because this port is open by default on the host's network (for TCP connections). Most other ports need to opened or forwarded explicitly (usually by configuring the modem).

Comment: the pc is at university. So I have no control about the network. I have only the computer. So I think I cant do anything. Are there other options to host more then one application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough for comment so this is why:
From what it seems it could be either firewall rule in your host running the container or one between the host to your house.
To test which on between the two I'd try to use nmap with --reason and --tracerout options, since we have connectivity in another port it's unlikely that there is a complete block between your home and the container so the traceroute wouldn't give much info but just in case.
Also if you have root access to the host machine or just to the iptables service try to stop it to check if that's the root cause for the block.

also check with docker ps if the port is bound to the port on the machine, should look something like this:

0.0.0.0:port --> tcp\port

where instead of port you have the port number

If it doesn't maybe it's due to some problem with the docker-compose up command so try to run the service with a simple docker run command